# itext7 - equivalent method for getJavascript in pdfReader class in itext7

Tags: javascript, itext, itext7

Is there any equivalent method for getJavascript in pdf reader in itext7? we are looking for sanitizing the pdf document for malicious content using itext7.

Comment: I have the same problem as Sushma.  The below answer from mkl did not find the JavaScript in a sample PDF I wish to reject that has a JavaScript popup upon opening the PDF.  Admittedly, the PDF does have some warnings when run through Adobe PreFlight.  However, I am trying to thwart people who may be actively trying to circumvent my checks!

Comment: The solution from mkl works using iText 7.1.1.  I could not get it to work  for my test PDF using 7.0.6.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see there is not a dedicated method for that in iText 7.

Essentially, though, the old `PdfReader.getJavaScript()` method merely looked for the **JavaScript** name tree and put all the values into a string buffer.

You can output these values like this in iText 7:

```
PdfNameTree javascript = pdfDocument.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.JavaScript);
Map<String, PdfObject> objs2 = javascript.getNames();
for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> entry : objs2.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println();

    PdfObject object = entry.getValue();
    if (object.isDictionary()) {
        object = ((PdfDictionary)object).get(PdfName.JS);
        if (object.isString()) {
            System.out.println(((PdfString)object).getValue());
        } else if (object.isStream()) {
            System.out.println(new String(((PdfStream)object).getBytes()));
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

*([ShowDocumentLevelJavaScript](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/meta/ShowDocumentLevelJavaScript.java#L79) test `testREJECT_ContainsJavaScript`)*

Obviously you can in a similar manner collect the pieces of JavaScript into some string buffer.

---

In a comment [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069731/james) claimed

> I tried using (and extending) your answer but cannot detect the JavaScript popup that fires when I open a sample PDF

Applying the above code to the PDF file provided by @James I get the output:

```
e.pdf Freeware Hinweis

if (app.viewerVersion>=5)
{
var result=app.alert(
    "Diese Datei wurde mit der Freeware Version von CIB e.pdf erzeugt.\n\nMöchten Sie nähere Informationen?"
    , 3
    , 2
    , "e.pdf Freeware Hinweis"
    );
if (result==4)
    getURL("http://www.cib.de/deutsch/products/pdfplugin/epdfbeta.asp", false);
}
```

The *JavaScript popup* can clearly be seen as an `app.alert` call here. Thus, I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: mkl, I tried using (and extending) your answer but cannot detect the JavaScript popup that fires when I open a sample PDF that I want to reject (due to said JavaScript).  Here is the embedded object in the PDF.  Any suggestions?           19 0 obj
<</JavaScript <</Names[(e.pdf Freeware XYZ)<</S/JavaScript/JS(if \(app.viewerVersion>=5\)\r\n{\r\nvar result=app.alert\(\r\n "Bad Message"\r\n , 3\r\n , 2\r\n , "e.pdf Freeware XYZ"\r\n \);\r\nif \(result==4\)\r\n getURL\("http://bad.place.com", false\);\r\n}\r\n\r\n)>>] >> >>endobj
20 0 obj

Comment: FYI, this same PDF was rejected in iText5 using getJavaScript().  Thanks for any time you can spare to help.

Comment: @James what do you mean by "rejected" in *"this same PDF was rejected in iText5 using getJavaScript()"*? That being said, the above code returns the same data as the iText 5 method: everything from the JavaScript name tree. This is **not** all JavaScript a pdf contains. If you think you have found a file for which the result differs, share that file - I'd need it for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I meant the JavaScript was identifed in getJavaScript() so *I* could reject the PDF.  I do not have access to a public server to post a link and do not see how to upload it here.  Are you willing to give me an email address?  Please send to tmp_2018-stackoverflow@yahoo.com

Comment: @James You'll find an address in my [stack overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl?tab=profile).

Comment: Email sent with subject:  "Stackoverflow PDF iText7 and JavaSript"

Comment: See above in my edit of my answer, I cannot reproduce your issue, the *JavaScript popup* can clearly be seen as an `app.alert` call in the output of the code. You might want to create an own question in which you give more details about your issue, in particular your pivotal code in this context.

Comment: mkl, thanks for your research.  I failed to replicate your result using iText 7.0.5 and 7.0.6 locally on Windows 7 using Eclipse. I cut and pasted your newer test code.  Only change was to use constructor PdfReader(String file) and add debugs before and after.  No output showed between the extra debugs and no errors logged.  The for loop is not entered.  Thanks, but I cannot expect any more help if you see success and I see failure running the same code.

Comment: I replicated mkl result using iText 7.1.1.  Unfortunately, 7.1.1 is not backward compatible with 7.0.6.  Why iText?  Why?  Oh, the humanity!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone able to use iText 7.1.1 or newer, I expect the solution by mkl to be better.  If you are forced to use iText 7.0.5 like I was, the following worked for my reference PDF:

```
    private static boolean hasJavascript(PdfDocument pdfDoc, String theFile) {
      int n = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
        List<PdfAnnotation> annotList = pdfPage.getAnnotations();
        if (ListUtility.hasData(annotList)) {
          for (PdfAnnotation annot : annotList) {
            if (annot.getSubtype().equals(PdfName.Link)) {
              continue;
            }
            PdfDictionary annotationAction = annot.getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.A);
            if (annotationAction != null && PdfName.JavaScript.equals(annotationAction.get(PdfName.S))) {
              PdfString javascript = annotationAction.getAsString(PdfName.JS);
              if (StringUtility.hasData(javascript.getValue())) {
                log.debug("JavaScript found in PDF on page " + i);
                log.trace(javascript.getValue());
                return true;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      String javaScriptInPdf = getJavaScriptFromPdfDocument(pdfDoc);
      if (StringUtility.hasData(javaScriptInPdf)) {
        log.debug("JavaScript found using iText 7");
        log.trace(javaScriptInPdf);
        return true;
      }
      log.debug("JavaScript not found in PDF");
      return false;
    }
    //
    private static String getJavaScriptFromPdfDocument(PdfDocument pdfDoc) {
      StringBuilder strBuf = new StringBuilder();
      try {
        PdfDictionary pdfDictionaryCatalog = pdfDoc.getCatalog().getPdfObject();
        if (pdfDictionaryCatalog == null) {
          log.trace("getJavaScriptFromPdfDocument(): pdfDictionaryCatalog null; return null");
          return null;
        }
        PdfDictionary pdfDictionaryNames = pdfDictionaryCatalog.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Names);
        if (pdfDictionaryNames == null) {
          log.trace("getJavaScriptFromPdfDocument(): PdfDictionary for PdfName.Names null; return null");
          return null;
        }
        PdfDictionary pdfDictionaryJavaScript = pdfDictionaryNames.getAsDictionary(PdfName.JavaScript);
        if (pdfDictionaryJavaScript == null) {
          log.trace("getJavaScriptFromPdfDocument(): PdfDictionary for PdfName.JavaScript null; return null");
          return null;
        }
        Set<Entry<PdfName, PdfObject>> set = pdfDictionaryJavaScript.entrySet();
        for (Entry<PdfName, PdfObject> pdfObjectEntry : set) {
          PdfObject pdfObj = pdfObjectEntry.getValue();
          if (pdfObj.isDictionary()) {
            getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary((PdfDictionary)pdfObj, strBuf);
          } else if (pdfObj.isArray()) {
            getJavaScriptFromPdfArray((PdfArray)pdfObj, strBuf);
          } else if (pdfObj.isString() && pdfObjectEntry.getKey().getValue().equals(PdfName.JS.getValue())) {
            strBuf.append(((PdfString) pdfObj).getValue());
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug(e,e);
      }
      return strBuf.toString();
    }
    //
    private static void getJavaScriptFromPdfArray(PdfArray pdfArray, StringBuilder strBuf) {
      if (pdfArray == null) {
        return;
      }
      for (PdfObject pdfObj : pdfArray) {
        // To get same output as getJavaScriptUsingiText559(), not appending String values found in array to strBuf
        if (pdfObj == null) {
          continue;
        }
        else if (pdfObj.isDictionary()) {
          getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary((PdfDictionary)pdfObj, strBuf);
        }
        else if (pdfObj.isArray()) {
          getJavaScriptFromPdfArray((PdfArray)pdfObj, strBuf);
        }
      }
    }
    //
    private static void getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary(PdfDictionary pdfDict, StringBuilder strBuf) {
      if (pdfDict == null) {
        return;
      }
      PdfObject pdfObj = pdfDict.get(PdfName.JS);
      if (pdfObj == null) {
        return;
      }
      if (pdfObj.isString()) {
        strBuf.append(((PdfString) pdfObj).getValue());
      }
      else if (pdfObj.isStream()) {
        strBuf.append(getStringFromPdfStream((PdfStream) pdfObj, TRUNCATE_PDF_STREAM_AT));
      }
      else if (pdfObj.isDictionary()) {
        getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary((PdfDictionary) pdfObj, strBuf);
      }
      else if (pdfObj.isArray()) {
       getJavaScriptFromPdfArray((PdfArray)pdfObj, strBuf);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old thread, still sharing my code to add couple of things, on top of what mkl and James wrote.

```
// iText V 7.0.2
//To get javascript that is added through OpenAction
PdfDocument srcPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(srcFilePath));
        PdfDictionary pdfDictionaryCatalog = srcPdf.getCatalog().getPdfObject();
        PdfDictionary namesDictionary = pdfDictionaryCatalog.getAsDictionary(PdfName.OpenAction);
        if(namesDictionary != null) {
            PdfObject pdfObj = namesDictionary.get(PdfName.JS);
            if(pdfObj != null) {
                StringBuilder strBuf = new StringBuilder();
                if (pdfObj.isDictionary()) {
                    getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary((PdfDictionary)pdfObj, strBuf);
                }else if (pdfObj.isArray()) {
                    getJavaScriptFromPdfArray((PdfArray)pdfObj, strBuf);
                } else if (pdfObj.isString()) {
                    strBuf.append(((PdfString) pdfObj).getValue());
                }
                System.out.println("*****OPENACTION****** "+strBuf.toString());
            }
        }
// To get java script available from NAMES dictionary 

namesDictionary = pdfDictionaryCatalog.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Names);
        if(namesDictionary != null) {
            PdfDictionary javascriptDictionary = namesDictionary.getAsDictionary(PdfName.JavaScript);
            if(javascriptDictionary != null) {
                StringBuilder strBuf = new StringBuilder();
                Set<Entry<PdfName, PdfObject>> set = javascriptDictionary.entrySet();
                for (Entry<PdfName, PdfObject> entry : set) {
                    PdfObject pdfObj = entry.getValue();
                    if (pdfObj.isDictionary()) {
                        getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary((PdfDictionary)pdfObj, strBuf);
                    }else if (pdfObj.isArray()) {
                        getJavaScriptFromPdfArray((PdfArray)pdfObj, strBuf);
                    } else if (pdfObj.isString() && entry.getKey().getValue().equals(PdfName.JS.getValue())) {
                        strBuf.append(((PdfString) pdfObj).getValue());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("*****JAVASCRIPT****** "+strBuf.toString());
            }
        }
// To get java script from name tree JAVASCRIPT
PdfNameTree nameTree = srcPdf.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.JavaScript);
        if(nameTree != null) {
            Map<String, PdfObject> objs = nameTree.getNames();
            if(objs != null) {
                StringBuilder strBuf = new StringBuilder();
                for (Entry<String, PdfObject> entry : objs.entrySet()) {
                    PdfObject pdfObj = entry.getValue();
                    if (pdfObj.isDictionary()) {
                        getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary((PdfDictionary)pdfObj, strBuf);
                    }else if (pdfObj.isArray()) {
                        getJavaScriptFromPdfArray((PdfArray)pdfObj, strBuf);
                    } else if (pdfObj.isString() && entry.getKey().equals(PdfName.JS.getValue())) {
                        strBuf.append(((PdfString) pdfObj).getValue());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("*****JAVASCRIPT NAMED TREE****** "+strBuf.toString());
            }
        }
// To get java script at the annotation action level
for (int i = 1; i <= srcPdf.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PdfPage page = srcPdf.getPage(i);
            List<PdfAnnotation> annotList = page.getAnnotations();
            if(annotList != null) {
                for (PdfAnnotation pdfAnnotation : annotList) {
                    if(pdfAnnotation.getPdfObject() != null) {
                        PdfDictionary annotationAction = pdfAnnotation.getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.A);
                        if (annotationAction != null && PdfName.JavaScript.equals(annotationAction.get(PdfName.S))) {
                            PdfString javascript = annotationAction.getAsString(PdfName.JS);
                            if(javascript != null) {
                                System.out.println("ANNOTATION "+javascript); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
/*getJavaScriptFromPdfDictionary() and getJavaScriptFromPdfArray() methods are the same from James answer. */
```